# Not able to redirect file content to a variable in %post part of the rpm spec

Tags: bash, rpm, rpm-spec

In the %post part of my spec file I am executing a binary which write a string into stdout. Now I want to capture that output string into a variable. But my variable is always null. Alternatively I am able to write the output into a file. But again not able to read it back into a variable. I want to redirect the output the binary into a variable or reading contents of a file into a variable would also work for me.

I tired in the spec file:

```
%post
/var/tmp/%{_installer_file} |& tee /var/tmp/status.txt
STATUS=`cat /var/tmp/status.txt`
echo "------------ status = $STATUS"
```

STATUS variable should be catching the string present in the status.txt file.

No error displaying.

Comment: what happens when you run these commands manually after installing the package? Are you sure something is really written to /var/tmp/status.txt ?

Comment: If run manually outside the rpm isntallation (or spec) everything works fine. Yes the line /var/tmp/%{_installer_file} writes into the file.

Comment: I have run a test, and this works fine on my machine. I get additional rpm output: `------------ status = status-output` ... what output do you get?